# Elasticsearch helm chart pods fails to run in openshift

Tags: security, elasticsearch, openshift, kubernetes-helm, okd

I'm trying to deploy elastic search 7.10.x in openshift . When in deploy helm chart response is successfully deployed . But when i check the pods it shows below error .

```
create Pod elasticsearch-dev1-master-0 in StatefulSet elasticsearch-dev1-master failed error: pods "elasticsearch-dev1-master-0" is forbidden: unable to validate against any security context constraint: [provider "anyuid": Forbidden: not usable by user or serviceaccount, provider restricted: .spec.securityContext.fsGroup: Invalid value: []int64{1000}: 1000 is not an allowed group, spec.initContainers[0].securityContext.runAsUser: Invalid value: 0: must be in the ranges: [1000620000, 1000629999], spec.initContainers[0].securityContext.privileged: Invalid value: true: Privileged containers are not allowed, spec.containers[0].securityContext.runAsUser: Invalid value: 1000: must be in the ranges: [1000620000, 1000629999], spec.initContainers[0].securityContext.runAsUser: Invalid value: 0: running with the root UID is forbidden, provider "hostmount-anyuid": Forbidden: not usable by user or serviceaccount, provider "machine-api-termination-handler": Forbidden: not usable by user or serviceaccount, provider "hostnetwork": Forbidden: not usable by user or serviceaccount, provider "hostaccess": Forbidden: not usable by user or serviceaccount, provider "scc-elasticsearch": Forbidden: not usable by user or serviceaccount, provider "node-exporter": Forbidden: not usable by user or serviceaccount, provider "privileged": Forbidden: not usable by user or serviceaccount]
```

Also i can i fix this by editing the default SCC . What is recommended way to deploy this in elasticsearhc helm chart in openshift ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this - seems you can just null out those runAsUser flags to avoid the permissions problem rather than assign extra privs to make it run as root.

https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/7.10/elasticsearch/examples/openshift/values.yaml

If you're using a different helm chart, provide a link to the one you're using.